# How to connect Kibana 7x with Elassandra 6.2.3?

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, kibana, elassandra

I was trying to connect my Elassandra to Kibana 7x but got some compatibility issue seems Elassandra uses Elasticsearch 6.2.3 and I was trying to connect to Kibana 7. Need help with upgrading the elasticsearch service to 7x or connecting kibana 7x to the elasticsearch 6x.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, Kibana needs to be on the same version as Elasticsearch.

Elassandra 6.2.3 uses Elasticsearch 6.2.3, so you need to use Kibana 6.2.3, you can't update the elasticsearch used by elassandra to a different version.

You would need to wait for the release of Elassandra 7.

But just remember that with the [changing](https://www.elastic.co/pricing/faq/licensing) of the Elasticsearch license and the [acquisition](https://community.datastax.com/questions/10894/the-future-of-elassandra.html) of Strapdata by Datastax, Elassandra 7 could take a long time to be released or not even be released.

In this [github issue](https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra/issues/314) you have more information about Elassandra 7.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Could you help me to configure apache solr with Cassandra that's a viable solution as of now.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have experience with Solr or Cassandra to help, I suggest you read the documentation of both projects to see what is possible to do and ask a new question in case of errors.